# Pattern State in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, state

I am trying to implement the Pattern State in C++.

I have my client: Player
State as the interface
and the 2 State: In and Out

This is my In.h:

```
#ifndef ODA_IN_H
#define ODA_IN_H

#include <vector>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Hand.h" 

using namespace std;

class In : public State {
    public:
        In(Player* player); 
        void doYouChange();
        Card throwCard(int i);
        void showHand();
        void setHand(vector<Card> &other);

    private:
        Player* player;
        Hand hand;
};

#endif
```

And the In.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "In.h"

using namespace std;

In::In(Player* player) {
    this->player = player;
    cout << player->getName() <<endl;
}
void In::doYouChange() {
    string sth;
    do {
        cout << player->getName() << ", Do you want to leave for this round?(Yes/No)?";
        cin >> sth;
    } while (sth != "No" && sth != "Yes");
    if (sth == "Yes") { 
        player->setState(player->getOut());
    }
}
Card In::throwCard(int i) {
    Card c = hand.getCard(i);
    return c;
}
void In::showHand() {
    hand.showHand();
}
void In::setHand(vector<Card> &other) {
    hand.setHand(other);
}
```

So the constructor can write out the name, while the doYouChange() method no. And later it breaks totally no message just memory junk:/

I call the doYouChange() from an other class like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < playersNb; ++i) {
  players[i].doYouChange();
}
```

The first player okay without name, the on the second it breaks.

I have absolutely no idea. I tried to reimplement and everything but nothing helped.

/********************************/
UPDATE:
Creating one Player (as a Client of Pattern State in the constructor I initialize also the states):

```
Player::Player(string n) {
    name = n;
    out = new Out(this);
    in = new In(this);
    this -> state = in;
}
```

And in the same class with the `for` I add players in the constructor:

```
players.push_back(Player(name));
```

Comment: Sounds like you have something pointing into uninitialized/deallocated memory. Did you try running in a debugger? What platform are you writing in so that we may suggest tools.

Comment: I am writing just in Sublime and using g++ in terminal.
Any tools which can help me debug this would be helpful!

Comment: Do you have gdb installed? it is a open source debugger for c++. (https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Answer (score 0):

This error will very likely occure due to the fact that `player` becomes invalid (/destroyed).
Consider the following code:

```
Player* player = new Player();

In inState(player); // will work
inState->doYouChange(); // will work

delete player;

inState->doYouChange(); // wont work
```

Without more details we cant give you a concrete solution but just general advices:

- Make sure that you know who manages your `player` objects
- Check the cases where these objects become destroyed, try to breakpoint them, do your `player` objects really become destroyed?
- Breakpoint the `doYouChange()` method and check the `player` object
- Consider using smart pointers to overcome an ownership problem: See [std::shared_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) (there are also many other libraries out there which might provide smart pointers better suiting your needs, e.g Poco or Boost)

Comment: I am not deleting the player. And actually it writes out if I want to change? But not the name.. So it gets invoked.
cout << player->getName() << ", Do you want to leave for this round?(Yes/No)?";

Comment: append a `std::endl` to that statement. And I dint said that it wont execute. If you delete `player` the pointer still holds a memory address, if you access `getName()` it will return you just the junk that is now on that memory location, the behaviour you described. Assuming that `getName()` actually returns a `char*` nothing will be printed if the returned `char*` points to a location with the value `0x00` (null-termination). The same can also apply to `std::string` (but its harder to explain). Without further informations / code its impossible to tell your problem

Comment: I added.
It prints out: ", Do you want to leave for this round?(Yes/No)?" So here it's just empty. After that it returns to the for. And with i=1 it throws the junk.

If you tell me I will attach whatever it can be useful. But I had no idea what else should I attach.

Comment: As I said, this information is barely useful. Without more code we cant tell your problem but its very likewise that `player` is invalid (or might contain no name?). I have pointed out multiply points to inspect and possible solutions. But with the current state of the question, there is nothing one can do for you anymore.

Comment: I can't say any more, I can add more samples, but don't know which part.
`cout<<players[i].getName();
players[i].doYouChange();`
Just a line before name is still working:/

Comment: How about the part where your player objects are stored, where you create the `In` objects and maybe a bit more of the calling code so that we can see whats going on.

Comment: Btw does it work when entering `No` as your changing the `player` object when you answere `Yes`?